# Use Hashicorp Vault with Ansible - plugin setup

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I want to use Hashicorp Vault with Ansible to retrieve username/password which I will use in Ansible playbook.

Vault is setup - I created a secret. What are the steps to integrate both? the documentation around plugins isn't that great.  I tried the file lookup from ansible and this works but how to use 3rd party plugins? Can somebody help me with the steps to follow?

1. Install the plugin, `pip install ansible-modules-hashivault`
2. What is the difference with https://github.com/jhaals/ansible-vault
   2.a The environment variables (VAULT ADDR & VAULT TOKEN) I put where?
3. Change `ansible.cfg` to point to `vault.py` which is located in "plugin" folder of my Ansible Project
4. To test basic integration, can I use the following playbook?
   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible-modules-hashivault

   ```
   - hosts: localhost
       -tasks:
          - hashivault_status:
            register: 'vault_status'
   ```

Tried this but I get:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 119, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 431, in _execute
    self._task.post_validate(templar=templar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/task.py", line 248, in post_validate
    super(Task, self).post_validate(templar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 371, in post_validate
    value = templar.template(getattr(self, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 359, in template
    d[k] = self.template(variable[k], preserve_trailing_newlines=preserve_trailing_newlines, fail_on_undefined=fail_on_undefined, overrides=overrides)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 331, in template
    result = self._do_template(variable, preserve_trailing_newlines=preserve_trailing_newlines, escape_backslashes=escape_backslashes, fail_on_undefined=fail_on_undefined, overrides=overrides)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 507, in _do_template
    res = j2_concat(rf)
  File "<template>", line 8, in root
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 193, in call
    return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 420, in _lookup
    instance = self._lookup_loader.get(name.lower(), loader=self._loader, templar=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/__init__.py", line 339, in get
    self._module_cache[path] = self._load_module_source('.'.join([self.package, name]), path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/__init__.py", line 324, in _load_module_source
    module = imp.load_source(name, path, module_file)
  File "/etc/ansible/ProjectA/lookup_plugins/vault.py", line 5
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

fatal: [win01]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
```

Comment: Do you mind fixing the syntax of your playbook first? Indentation is broken and `tasks` is a key, not another item.

Comment: Vault offers a simple REST API - you can even use [uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) module. There are surprisingly many lookup plugins for Ansible and even though it should be simple, finding one that works among all of them is surprisingly difficult - [the one you already found](https://github.com/jhaals/ansible-vault) works.

Comment: And I don't really understand what you ask here about. The README for the plugin is super-clear and gives good examples. Are you asking what [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variablehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are?

Answer (score 6):

Since you put so many eggs into the post, that I have no clue what the question is really about, here's something to get you going with the native lookup plugin and `jhaals/ansible-vault`.

- you can create `lookup_plugins` in the current directory and save [`vault.py`](https://github.com/jhaals/ansible-vault/blob/master/vault.py) inside;
- the `VAULT_ADDR` and `VAULT_TOKEN` environment variables are as you see them in the script;

The Bash script below (it uses `screen` and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you might need to install them) runs Vault in dev mode, sets the secret, and runs Ansible playbook which queries the secret with two lookup plugins:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200

if [[ ! $(pgrep -f "vault server -dev") ]]; then
    echo \"vault server -dev\" not running, starting...
    screen -S vault -d -m vault server -dev
    printf "sleeping for 3 seconds\n"
    sleep 3
else
    echo \"vault server -dev\" already running, leaving as is...
fi

vault write secret/hello value=world excited=yes
export VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault token-create -format=json | jq -r .auth.client_token)
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars="vault_token=${VAULT_TOKEN}"
```

and `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve secret/hello using native hashi_vault plugin
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/hello token={{ vault_token }} url=http://127.0.0.1:8200') }}"

    - name: Retrieve secret/hello using jhaals vault lookup
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('vault', 'secret/hello') }}"
```

In the end you should get:

```
TASK [Retrieve secret/hello using native hashi_vault plugin] *******************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "world"
}

TASK [Retrieve secret/hello using jhaals vault lookup] *************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "excited": "yes",
        "value": "world"
    }
}
```

The word `world` was fetched from Vault.

Comment: Thx techraf, I got both plugins up & running now!